# Private:Autodraft post created automatically, Is that normal?

Tags: custom-post-types

I created a new post type and for the public parameter i made it false and when i checked this post type and tried to add new items to it i found out that an item titled Auto Draft — Private is already there, so is that normal or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you start writing a post, but haven't hit save yet, autosaving will create a draft post for you. It'll get cleaned up/replaced on save. You can also delete it if you don't want the contents

Comment: the thing is i didnt click the create new item button so as soon as i added new post type in my functions.php and checked the admin dashboard the post with draft private is already there.

Comment: And you're absolutely sure you didn't open up a post editor even for the briefest of moments? WP won't create a post like that without doing that. What you describe does not happen in vanilla WP out of the box